# Computational Complexity of SPADE, GSP and others

Tags: time-complexity, sequential-pattern-mining

Does anybody know the computational complexity of SPADE, GSP, FreeSpan and PrefixSpan algorithm. I would like to have a comparisson in between these algorithms.

Comment: [A Survey on Sequential Pattern Mining Algorithms](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0138/51785494c4cadfac7e06b8a01634d04ae4c6.pdf). This resource might be helpful

Comment: thank you I read that but it was not that helpful. I read also the Data mining book for Zaki. It has complexity for most of them, except ECLAT and FreeSpan.